# Android Centering the content

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm a total beginner in Android layout, but I want to center the content vertically and horizontally.

So this book I'm reading says this:

```
 <LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:background="@color/background"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:padding="30dip"
   android:orientation="horizontal" >
   <LinearLayout
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="center" >
     ...component.. etc...
```

This works and I think i get it, except Eclipse says:

> This linearlayout or its parent is useless; transfer the background
>   attribute to the other view

But I do not understand this?

Comment: post your entire xml file.

Comment: RelativeLayout has a lot of centering stuff. But why LinearLayout in a Linearlayout .O

Comment: It does not seriously affect the application performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This linearlayout or its parent is useless; transfer the background
>   attribute to the other view

means that you can manage the entire layout by the parent it self, you are unnecessarily adding  another `LinearLayout`  which can degrade the layout performance

You can use  `android:gravity="center"` instead of `android:layout_gravity="center"` which a child supplies to its parent.

**Solution**

you can combine  your linear layouts as

```
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:background="@color/background"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" 
   android:padding="30dip"
   >
```

Comment: I feel like your answere is the best one. Since I had to feeling i should combine to two to one, which I orginally thougth, but then the background becomes half visible. This solution on the other hand works great! I do not really understand what gravity=center does and why it works. Could u explain this a bit further?

Comment: android:gravity="center" in a parent layout will align it child views to center &   android:layout_gravity="center" in a child view will align it in center of its parent....

Comment: Thank you figured it out ;)

Answer (score 0):

add `android:background` parameter in both LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

> This linearlayout or its parent is useless; transfer the background
>   attribute to the other view

This is a warning triggered when any `Layout` has only one child which is also a `Layout`. In your case `LinearLayout`. In these cases one of other can be removed without any problems. It is recommended to remove these redundant layouts.  It is.. as it says just a warning, it wont cause any exception, but if you remove that redundant layout that will help improve overall performance

Answer (score 0):

You should share your full code so that everyone get the whole scenario of your problem. Any way you can follow three way to do the things.

Approach One :

**android:layout_centerInParent="true"**

Above code will make your layout center horizontally and vertically.

Approach two :

And if you want to do individually.(May be needs sometimes)

**android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"**

**android:layout_centerVertical="true"**

Approach three :

**android:gravity="center"** (Though I see you have used. May be you have missed any point inside code).

Hope this will help you. Happy coding.